# Spring Boot application won't run JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I am building a spring web application that allows sending code snippets to a database. I have an HTML endpoint where you can enter some text and click a button so that the text is sent to a database. Here's the html code:

[image]

The send.js script is responsible for taking the input text and casting it to json. Here's the send.js code:

```
    function send() {
    let object = {
        "code": document.getElementById("code_snippet").value
    };

    let json = JSON.stringify(object);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/api/code/new', false)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
}
```

For some reason when I press the button nothing happens. I tried debugging the app and it seems like it doesn't execute the js code. I had some issues with even accessing the send.js in html at first, intellij just couldn't see it for some reason. This is my resources structure:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I tried adding this instead of just checking if status is equal to 200 and I dont get either of the alerts

```
if (xhr.status != 200) {
    alert("Something went wrong!");
} else if (xhr.status == 200){
    alert("Success!");
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the script doesn't work even when I put it inside the script tag, not through src

Comment: I can go to the send.js file with ctrl+left click, so I guess pathing to the file is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html file you have id="code-snippet", and in the js you have "code_snippet", try fixing that

Comment: I changed it and it still doesn't work